# psql: update a column consisting of an array of strings, merging another array of strings and removing duplicates

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-update

I tried the following:

```
SELECT tags FROM articles WHERE id = 1;
=> {news,new} 
UPDATE articles SET tags = uniq(array_cat(tags, '{new,trendy,latest}')) WHERE id = 1;
=> [1]
SELECT tags FROM articles WHERE id = 1;
=> {news,new,trendy,latest}
```

but at UPDATE command, I get:

`ERROR: function uniq(text[]) does not exist`

Now is there a way to add non existing tags only in one UPDATE command?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I guess a solution could be to iterate update for each individual tag, adding a where constraint such as:
`WHERE NOT ('tag-name' = ANY(tags))`
but I wonder if we can do it in one shot.

EDIT2:

Found this https://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/083k9e85rb/array-cat-without-duplicity but seems even more complicated then iterating over each tag.

Comment: Assuming you are referring to the function uniq() from the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.27.6) extension, then this won't work. That function only works with `int[]` not `text[]`

Comment: So is there a way to add non existing tags only in one UPDATE command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two ways:

```
UPDATE articles SET tags = ARRAY(SELECT unnest(tags) UNION SELECT unnest(ARRAY['new', 'trendy', 'latest'])) WHERE id = 1;
```

or:

```
UPDATE articles SET tags = ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT unnest(array_cat(tags, '{new,trendy,latest}'))) WHERE id = 673738;
```

Feel free to post a different solution. Thanks! :-)